# Set flask wtform's default date as today

Tags: python, date, flask, date-format, flask-wtforms

A basic flask wtform with 2 input dates and a submit button will be :

```
class WelcomeForm(FlaskForm):
startdate = DateField('Start Date', format='%Y-%m-%d',validators=(validators.DataRequired(),))
enddate = DateField('End Date', format='%Y-%m-%d',validators=(validators.DataRequired(),))
submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

How do we set default dates for the form?

Note : This is only for date and not datetime.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the answer to my question, hope it helps others who are looking for it.

```
    from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
    class WelcomeForm(FlaskForm):
    today = date.today()
    sevendaysago = date.today() - timedelta(days = 7)
    startdate = DateField('Start Date', format='%Y-%m-%d',default=sevendaysago,validators=(validators.DataRequired(),))
    enddate = DateField('End Date', format='%Y-%m-%d', default = today, validators=(validators.DataRequired(),))
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```